# Filter Grouped Dataset by Another Column in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a dataset with multiple rows of the same individual

```
set.seed(420)
df <- data.frame(ind = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",5), rep("C",4)), value = seq(1:12), location = sample(c("first", "second", "third"), 12, replace = TRUE))

df
  ind value location
1    A     1    first
2    A     2    first
3    A     3   second
4    B     4   second
5    B     5    first
6    B     6    first
7    B     7    first
8    B     8    first
9    C     9    first
10   C    10    first
11   C    11    first
12   C    12    third
```

I would like to find the `location` for each `ind`ividual for which the `value` column is highest.

So the final dataset would like:

```
ind    value    location
A      3        second
B      8        first
C      12       third
```

Is this possible to do with `group_by` and `summarize` or `mutate` in `dplyr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it using `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(ind) %>% slice_max(value)
```

Or

```
df %>% group_by(ind) %>% filter(value == max(value))
```

### Addressing your question

#### mutate()

For `mutate()`, it would require extra steps to filter the data (i.e. made the data unique), since it would not shrink the data by group.

1. First `group_by` as usual,
2. Make sure we `arrange` by value, since we'll use the position to extract the `location` associated with maximum value
3. Set `value` column to the `max(value)`
4. Set `location` column to the `last(location)`, since we've sorted the `value`, `last(location)` should be the `location` of the `max(value)`
5. Only keep the `distinct` rows

```
df %>% group_by(ind) %>% 
  arrange(value) %>% 
  mutate(value = max(value), 
         location = last(location)) %>% 
  distinct(value, .keep_all = T)
```

#### summarise()

Similar logic from `mutate()` can be applied to `summarise()`, but we do not need the `distinct()` step, since the `summarise()` would naturally shrink the data by group, but remember we need  `arrange(value)` to make sure the values are sorted properly.

```
df %>% group_by(ind) %>% 
  arrange(value) %>% 
  summarize(value = max(value), location = last(location))
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ind [3]
  ind   value location
  <chr> <int> <chr>   
1 A         3 second  
2 B         8 first   
3 C        12 third
```